# URL for russian language - cyrillic or latin

Tags: url, cyrillic

I am doing website translation to russian language and I dont know what is better, more used for URL namespace - cyrillic or latin, for example xyz.com/команда or xyz.com/komanda. I found when I was googling more sites in latin. Is it more used in Russia?

Comment: This is probably a pretty subjective question, but I'd personally tend to prefer the second route.

Answer (score 0):

depends on server, usually browser converts not Latin url symbols to UTF-8 and sends, server may accept them or reject.

For example, all these 3 URL below are identical:

[https://www.rabota.ru/vacancy/программист/](https://www.rabota.ru/vacancy/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82/)

https://www.rabota.ru/vacancy/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82/

Cyrillic symbols UTF-8 encoding:
%D0%BF - п
%D1%80 - р
%D0%BE - о

and so on