# Greek letters as parameters in URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, encoding, urlencode

I have been struggling to pass greek letters as parameters in a URL (e.g. [http://localhost/test.html?text=Καλημέρα](http://localhost/test.html?text=%CE%9A%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%AD%CF%81%CE%B1))

For this reason I have created a simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<body>

<p id="text"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getQueryVariable(variable)
    {
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
      }
      return(false);
    }
    var i = getQueryVariable("text");

    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = i;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

however when I open the site from a browser, javascript seems to fail to properly handle the input parameter and print it as Greek text

Here is what I get in the browser's window:

%CE%9A%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%AD%CF%81%CE%B1

instead of Καλημέρα.

Ι thought it was a matter of encoding that is why I plassed a UTF-8 statement at the top of the html. Can you please advise me on how I should properly pass something "Greek" as url input?

Comment: Maybe it's help for u https://stackoverflow.com/a/44592051/2661164

Comment: thank you! However, my problem is not how to pass it in the URL, but why I cannot print it as Greek!

Comment: `decodeURI('%CE%9A%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%AD%CF%81%CE%B1')` // "Καλημέρα"

Comment: @roni Browsers by default encode URLs using ASCII. In your js code you can decode it using decodeURIComponent().

Comment: URLs always get encoded, so you just need to decode it again

Answer (score 5):

You just need to take care of the URL decoding yourself in this instance.

[`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) is what you should use for that:

```
if(pair[0] == variable){return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);}
```

(If you only have Greek letters inside of the value, that should do. If the parameter name itself could have Greek letters as well, then you might want to decode `pair[0]` as well, before you compare it to the name stored in `variable`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built in JS methods `encodeURI` and `decodeURI` for this, like so...

```
var url = "http://somesite.com?q=Καλημέρα", 
    encoded = encodeURI(url),
    decoded = decodeURI(encoded);

console.log("encoded:", encoded);
//=> http://somesite.com?q=%CE%9A%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%AD%CF%81%CE%B1
console.log("decoded:", decoded);
//=> http://somesite.com?q=Καλημέρα
```

Hope that helped :)

[encodeURI @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

Answer (score 1):

This [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) with example like you question)

Solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<body>

<p id="text"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getQueryVariable(variable)
    {
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if(pair[0] == variable){return decodeURI(pair[1]);}
      }
      return(false);
    }
    var i = getQueryVariable("text");

    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = i;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @roni, I testing with [decodeURIComponetnt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) from CBroe in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51609011/2661164) and this better solution